# how to find out in snowflake ? who drop/deleted my table in snowflake?

Tags: query-optimization, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-delete

I want complete rca for table deleted or drop in snowflake, not sure how the table got deleted. any hints how I can see who have deleted it ? as all the dependent pipes got failed.

Comment: FYI You can undrop the table if it's not too late.

Comment: yea, thats true, but I am looking for specific solution on RCA.
who, how, when that did..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use the Access_History view.
Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/access-history.html#write-operations-in-the-access-history-view

Also, on more of when and who did it - query-history-view
Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html#query-history-view